# install run Tomcat on VPS/Burstnet

Tags: jvm, vps

What is the minimum memory requirement to start JVM?
I have the cheapest VPS Burstnet (512mb memory) and installed java.
When I type java, it says

```
$java
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

When I type top, there is still around around 400MB free memory.

The support tells me the only solution is to increase my memory, I doubt his suggestion. In case it is caused by insufficient memory,I tried to create a swap file, however swap file  is not allowed due to my VPS runs on OpenVS, and OpenVs does not allow swap files. http://writereadspread.blogspot.com/2010/08/swap-on-vpsopenvs.html

I would be very much appreciated if you can answer any of the following questions:

What is the cause of the issue?
What is the minimum memory requirement for installing JRE and JDK?
If u r running java apps on VPS, what is your memory, and which host r u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Tomcat on VPS:
* if openjkd installed, uninstall
* install sun-java [linux installation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-linux-self-extracting-138783.html)
* install tomcat
* run `export JAVA_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=64m -Xms16M -Xmx64m"`
* start Tomcat `./startup.sh`